# Delete all rows in a table which a column has the same name repeated 2 or more times (but i don't know their names)

Tags: sqlite, rows

I would like to delete all the rows in a table where the names of a column are the same...

But I do not know the names of the values in column_1.

Always column_1 will be the one with repeats... column_2 will not. It's possible to do that? Thank you.

Example:

| column_1 | column_2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 4 |
| 3 | 5 |
| 4 | 6 |
| 5 | 7 |
| 5 | 8 |
| 5 | 9 |

Expected:

| column_1 | column_2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 4 | 6 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a subquery to help you with that:

```
DELETE  FROM `TableName` where column_1 in 
    (select column_1 FROM 
        (select column_1 FROM `TableName` GROUP BY `column_1` HAVING count(column_1)>1) AS t1
    )
```